# is there any solution to curses library problem?

Tags: python, windows, python-curses

so I was programing a snake game with curses and it's already there but python tells me that it doesn't exist

```
import random
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
sh, sw = screen.getmaxyx()
curses.curs_set(0)
window = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
window.keypad(1)
window.timeout(100)
snk_x = sw//4
snk_y= sh//2
snk=[[snk_y,snk_x],[snk_y,snk_x-1],[snk_y,snk_x-2]]
food = [sh//2,sw//2]
```

> "D:\python projects\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/pythonProject/snake
> game.py" Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\pythonProject\snake game.py", line 2, in 
> import curses   File "C:\Users\yasse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\curses_*init*_.py",
> line 13, in 
> from _curses import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'

Comment: Python's standard `curses` module doesn't support Windows.  There are replacement versions that do: `pip install windows-curses` for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try entering this:

```
pip install windows-curses
```

into your terminal that should fix it